# Scala Deadline.time not giving the time duration that was set when creating Deadline object

Tags: scala, duration

I am using a Deadline object as shown below.

```
scala> val d1 = Duration.create(10, "seconds").fromNow
d1: scala.concurrent.duration.Deadline = Deadline(1048157612536608 nanoseconds)
```

When I try to print the time that I had set (10 seconds in this example), it is printing some incorrect time.

```
scala> d1.time
res0: scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration = 1048157612536608 nanoseconds

scala> d1.time.toSeconds
res1: Long = 1048157
```

What is the correct way to get the time from Deadline object that I had set when creating the same object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deadline is NOT meant to be used that way. It is basically a wrapper around `System.nanoTime` which allows easy addition of `Duration` values.

`System.nanoTime` is NOT intended to be used as a clock. It is intended to be used for calculating time differences.

You can see it if you use `Deadline` as intended, that is as something to produce a time difference:

```
// diff on _rounded_ values
10.seconds.fromNow.time.toSeconds - Deadline.now.time.toSeconds // 10L
// diff on _actual_ values - by the time we start calculating `-` it should be less than 10s
10.seconds.fromNow - Deadline.now // 9999991191 nanoseconds
```